# How can I play two audio files simultaneously in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio

Is there any way in visual studio through which i can play two audio at the same time in Unity?

main audio file has been done but when I try to play second file with it it throws error.

[image: photo 1]

[image: photo 2]

[image: photo 3]

[image: photo 4]

[image: photo 5]

Comment: Of course. Have 2 sources. Play both.   What is the error?

Comment: Hi, the use of images for code/errors causes many problems. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You will need two audio sources, each source is a independent object and you can use it inifinite times just make sure you have compatible audio sources (**AIFF, WAV, MP3, and Ogg**)

```
    public AudioClip audioClip1; // First audio clip
    public AudioClip audioClip2; // Second audio clip

    private AudioSource audioSource1; // AudioSource for audioClip1
    private AudioSource audioSource2; // AudioSource for audioClip2

    private void Start()
    {
        // Create AudioSources
        audioSource1 = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
        audioSource2 = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();

        // Assign audio clips
        audioSource1.clip = audioClip1;
        audioSource2.clip = audioClip2;

        // Play audio files simultaneously
        audioSource1.Play();
        audioSource2.Play();
    }
```

If you prefer using the Unity editor without writing code, you can create an empty GameObject and attach two AudioSource components to it. Then assign the respective audio files to each AudioSource component.